# Cryptographically secure random integer between two values

Tags: c#, random

I have been using the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to create a random integer. This will generate a random integer between the lower and upper bounds of an integer.

```
private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCryptoServiceProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public int Execute(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    // initialize an array of bytes equal to the number of bytes in an integer
    var numberOfBytes = sizeof(int);
    var bytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];

    // fill the array with random bytes
    rngCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(bytes);

    // convert the byte array to an integer
    var bitsAsInteger = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    
    return bitsAsInteger;
}
```

Now I want to generate a random integer between two integers. From what I have read, this is not a trivial task. So, I thought I might be able to randomly seed the `System.Random` class and use the `Next()` functionality to do the math. Is this a sensible approach?

```
private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCryptoServiceProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public int Execute(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    // initialize an array of bytes equal to the number of bytes in an integer
    var numberOfBytes = sizeof(int);
    var bytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];

    // fill the array with random bytes
    rngCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(bytes);

    // convert the byte array to an integer
    var bitsAsInteger = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

    // use the random integer to seed the non cryptographically secure Random class
    var random = new System.Random(bitsAsInteger);
    
    // use the Next() functionality to do the math to get a random number between two values
    var randomInteger = random.Next(lowerBound, upperBound);
    
    return randomInteger;
}
```

Is there another way to achieve the same result without having to use `System.Random`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus.

```
private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCryptoServiceProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public int Execute(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    // initialize an array of bytes equal to the number of bytes in an integer
    var numberOfBytes = sizeof(int);
    var bytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];

    // fill the array with random bytes
    rngCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(bytes);

    // convert the byte array to an integer
    var bitsAsInteger = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    var m = (int)(Math.Abs(bitsAsInteger) % ((long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue));
    return m + lowerBound;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why Math.Abs is used? I'm not sure this would work if the bounds were sufficiently large. If upper bound was int.Max and lower bound was int.Min then we'd get an overflow?

Comment: Choose, but even Math.Mod introduces bias in most cases. Crudely speaking, you need to ignore values from leftovers. For example if you want a number between 90 and 180, from a single byte, then you (mod 90), but 90 only goes into 256 twice with 76 left over. So if the random byte is 180 or over, you should discard and try again.

Comment: Check out https://bitbucket.org/merarischroeder/number-range-with-no-bias/src/master/Code/TestNonRandomBias/TestNonRandomBias/Extensions/RNGCryptoServiceProviderExtensions.cs

Comment: I used ABS because I want to generate number 0 to difference. In C# modulus operator is actually a reminder operator, in example -5 % 3 = -2 but it should be 1. For, overflow you are soo right. I changed it to long on code. And @Todd is right.